# OnScreen keyboard in Windows 10 IE kiosk mode

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, kiosk

**What we have:**

- Windows 10 Pro amd64 1607 all updates installed
- for one user registry key `HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\shell` changed to `C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe -k superuser.com`
- configured autologon for this user with [Sysinternals Autologon](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/autologon.aspx)
- there in no hardware keyboard or mouse - **only touchscreen!**
- Web page works only in Internet Explorer.
- Assigned Access not appropriate for other reasons.

**The problem:**

- user can not enter data into the input field - the keypad is not displayed when input field focused.

Any solution how to enable onscreen keyboard popup, ONLY when input field focused?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had the same issue with a custom shell On Win 10. Adding the following two reg entries fixed it for me:

`HKCU\Software\Microsoft\TabletTip\1.7\EnableDesktopModeAutoInvoke` = 1

`HKCU\Software\Microsoft\windows\CurrentVersion\ImmersiveShell\TabletMode` = 1

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in hardware and it's driver.

For Windows Ink works it requires that in system present HID device with **Usage 0x000D** and **Page Usage 0x0004** (see [Microsoft docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/drivers/hid/hid-clients-supported-in-windows) for supported HID clients list).

But my touchscreen driver was implements only **Mouse class driver and mapper driver**

Answer (score 0):

Execute `TabTip.exe` to start the onscreen keyboard.

Otherwise you may need to write a proper kiosk application that can invoke on-screen keybaord when needed.

---

An alternative may be to use Edge browser and [Assigned Access](https://web.archive.org/web/20161207115437/https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/itpro/windows/manage/set-up-a-kiosk-for-windows-10-for-desktop-editions)(perma link).

Assigned Access will display the app above the lock screen. This has the advantage of allowing the onscreen keyboard to function intuitively, while also locking all functionality of the device outside of the application (edge browser).

There are some other settings you might want to have locked down, the linked article has several examples.

Comment: Web page works only in Internet Explorer. Assigned Access not appropriate for other reasons. 
It will work `tabtip.exe` without  `explorer.exe` process? Now try it.

Comment: Starting `TabTip.exe` has no effect. The new process will appear, but no on-screen keyboard.

Comment: I am running kiosk mode with group policy setting for a kiosk account "Custom User Interface" that runs a specified kiosk application. I do not see the keyboard popping up when I select an input field in the application.

Answer (score 0):

I had a same issue. Adding the following two reg entries fixed it for me:

**HKLM**\Software\Microsoft\TabletTip\1.7\EnableDesktopModeAutoInvoke = 1

**HKLM**\Software\Microsoft\windows\CurrentVersion\ImmersiveShell\TabletMode = 1

Comment: Why have you copied previous answer?

Comment: Itś not the same. HKLM instead HKCU...

Answer (score 0):

Same problem & nothing here worked for me. 
I figured out a workaround though.

In my case, I changed the shell to load Chrome. 
I googled the hell out of this and there doesn't appear to be a proper fix for it. So I went to the Chrome Web Store and searched "on screen keyboard". Installed an extension called "Virtual Keyboard".

Problem solved but that's only if you're using the Chrome browser.